# How to change code for plot function of a regression?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I want to plot more than one graph in R. However, I don't want to use the par() or layout() function. I want to change the plots by pressing enter just like the inbuilt plot function for a regression. How can I write my own code for that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `menu()` from `utils` and `switch`:

```
keep_loop = TRUE
while (keep_loop) {
  switch (menu(c("cars", "iris", "exit"), title = "Which dataset to plot?"),
          1 == {
            plot(cars)
            lines(lowess(cars))
          },
          2 == {
            plot(iris[, 1:2])
            lines(lowess(iris[, 1:2]))
          },
          3 == {
            keep_loop = FALSE
          })
}
```

If you just want a prompt without ability to select plots (or go back), use `readline()`

```
plot(cars)
invisible(readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue"))
lines(lowess(cars))
```

Comment: I did not know this could be done so easily, my compliments.